# Show that $\sum_{j=1}^{m} c_j \exp(-2 \gamma \lVert \mathbf{x_i} - \mathbf{x_j} \rVert^2) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

How would you show that $\sum_{j=1}^{m} c_j \exp(-2 \gamma \lVert \mathbf{x_i} - \mathbf{x_j} \rVert^2) = 0$ for all $0 \leq i \leq m$ and positive $\gamma$? $c_j$ is a constant and $\mathbf{x_j}$ is a vector. In other words, I want to show that for the corresponding matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{c} = [c_1, c_2, ..., c_m]$, we have that $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$ is the only solution to $\mathbf{Ac}= \mathbf{0}$, aka.$\mathbf{A}$ has full rank. If it helps, the prove would show that the number of basis vectors making up $span \{\exp(-2 \gamma \lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_j} \rVert^2)\ |\ \mathbf{x_j} \in \mathbb{X} \}$ for the input space $\mathbb{X}$ is infinite. Thus, any way of showing this is helpful :)

Comment: Is this supposed to be true for any $\mathbf{c}$? Take for example $c_0=1$ and all other coefficients to be $0$.

Comment: Do you mean $Ac=0$ instead of $Ax=0$?

Comment: @angryavian of course! thanks

Comment: @Andrei I edited the text, thanks for the question

Comment: [possibly related question on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35634/how-to-prove-that-the-radial-basis-function-is-a-kernel)